# List of important IoT references

Tags: protocols

This is a list of useful references and resources in the IoT environment.

- [Standardization Bodies](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/399/78)
- IoT Protocol Specifications

---

If the accompanying [meta post](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126/discussion-about-the-iot-reference-question) will validate the usefulness of this question, I'll ask the SE staff to make it CW.

Comment: To the down-voter, as a meta post is already open to discussion please elaborate your problem about the idea so improvements can be made or the idea can be reconsidered.

Comment: I am busy creating my own list, just like this, and would be willing to add my stuff to yours. There are lots of lists on GitHub, so you could host it there. Personally, I don't just want to see a static list. I would like a Wizard or search capability to help me find what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi @Mawg since this was decided to be off-topic (and actually even has delete votes on it) I don't see a benefit in adding it here. Maybe a list on meta is a better idea.

Comment: Sounds good to me - please link

Answer (score 11):

I would add to the list [OPC/UA](https://opcfoundation.org/about/opc-technologies/opc-ua/)

> The OPC Unified Architecture (UA), released in 2008, is a platform independent service-oriented architecture that integrates all the functionality of the individual OPC Classic specifications into one extensible framework.

Comment: Welcome to IoT! Since the other answer is *community wiki*, you can always just edit it and add your suggestion there (I believe that's the point of the list). Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 6):

### Standardization Bodies

- [3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org/)—the 3rd Generation Partnership Project. *The project covers cellular telecommunications network technologies, including radio access, the core transport network, and service capabilities - including work on codecs, security, quality of service - and thus provides complete system specifications.* Interesting standards regarding IoT are [LTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_(telecommunication)) and [UMTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_(telecommunication)).
- [IEEE IoT Initiative](http://iot.ieee.org/)

  The Internet of Things Initiative of the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers—one of largest standardization organizations of the world. One example in the IoT domain is [IEEE 802.15.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4)
- [ITU-T](http://www.itu.int/en/Pages/default.aspx)—the telecommunication standardization sector of the International Telecommunication Union. Another entity that sets international standards and recommendations like the [ITU-T Y.2060 "Overview of the Internet of Things"](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/gsi/iot/Pages/default.aspx). The Internet of Things is currently covered by the [Study Group 20](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/studygroups/2017-2020/20/Pages/default.aspx).
- [Object Management Group](http://www.omg.org/hot-topics/iot-standards.htm), an international, open membership, not-for-profit technology standards consortium, which also provides standardization in the IoT and IIoT domain.
- [OPC/UA](https://opcfoundation.org/about/opc-technologies/opc-ua/) - The OPC Unified Architecture (UA), released in 2008, is a platform independent service-oriented architecture that integrates all the functionality of the individual OPC Classic specifications into one extensible framework.